# Feature Selection-regression

Tags: regression, feature-selection

I am trying to predict the overall age of an opportunity (creation date - closing date) this is my response variable

lets say an opportunity  passes through 3 stages
to close

For example: Opp x stayed in

- stage 1 : 30 days
- stage 2 : 10 days
- stage 3:  20 days

At stage 3 I might close it same date or wait some time

so if I waited some time to close, it will be createdon: 22/11/2018 & closedon:9/2/2019

There is opp y , where i close it in same date of stage 3, so createdon:22/11/2018 and closedate: 21/1/2019

Summary

```
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| OppName | oppAge | stage1 | stage2 | stage3 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
| x       |     79 |     30 |     10 |     20 |
| y       |     60 |     30 |     10 |     20 |
+---------+--------+--------+--------+--------+
```

my question is :

1. Can I include stage1,2,3 as my independent variables to create a regression model?
2. They seem to nearly make the model ideal, so is it better to include maybe only stage 1? without 2 &3

### Work Done

- I transformed stages to a categorical nature, for example <30 days to 1 month
  30-60 day transformed it to 1-2months and so on

  ```
      +-----------+-----------+-----------+
      |  stage1   |  stage2   |  stage3   |
      +-----------+-----------+-----------+
      | <1month   | 1~2months | 6~7months |
      | 1~2months | <1month   | 3~4months |
      | 6~7months | <1month   | 2~3months |
      +-----------+-----------+-----------+
  ```
- Then I did one-hot encode to the stages
- Then I stopped ,wasn't sure if its wrong to include all the created dummy variables, or I should remove all stage 3